What do the inhabitants of Mongo name themselves?
I am curious if there is a demonym for the people who reside on the fictional planet Mongo. Flash Gordon Wiki only refers to them as "The people of Mongo", and I don't think we can call them Mongols. Is there any legitimate reference to how individuals from Mongo are referred to? Thanks.

My father, who was a Flash Gordon fan from way back, used "Mongonians," but I don't know of any source for that apart from his imagination.

Just to clarify, are we talking about the original comics, the old TV serial, the 80s movie, or some other iteration?

According to the Flash Gordon Wiki:

Mongonians, Mongoans or Mongori are the inhabitants of planet Mongo although the designation does occasionally not include
all of the planets races or subspecies.
No general self-designation of the inhabitants of Mongo was used in the original Comic Strips, the term "Mongan" was used in the
comic book acompanying the 1989 Movie adaption though only for Ming's
people excluding Tree Men and Hawk Men. "Mongoan" was used in
Flash Gordon #6 July 2009 by Brendan Deneen and Paul Green.
"Mongori" was introduced in Flash Gordon #1 Jeff Parker, Evan
Shaner and Jordie Bellaire, Flash Gordon #1 April 2014.

So, I guess you can take your pick between Mongonian, Mongan, Mongoan, and Mongori.
Although, as stated above, the inhabitants of Mongo never referred to themselves by any of these names in the original comic strip, only by race, e.g., Hawkmen, Lion Men, etc.

Thank you David for your answer.

You're welcome.
